# Deploying ASP.NET web service

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-services

I have made a web service using Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Basic. I would like to put this service on a server so I can reference it rather than have it on local host.

It works fine on my localhost/IIS at the moment

Is it possible to deploy these web services to a basic host such as from GoDaddy or do you need a special server such as somee.com?

I just want my WS to be referencable from my client app, such as those at webservicesx.net

Thank in advance

Comment: Server needs IIS, it means you have to mount your web service on a windows server. You may be interested in using Mono so you can mount your service on Apache although you'd have to search a server that supports Appache with mono-mod module.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need a database in the server if there is not one created on my web service? (It's just a simple temperature converter) thanks

Comment: if your service is not saving data in a database then you don't need a database. Also, if your service is a temperature converter then You may be interested in using another platform like php, servers that supports this language are cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I managed to get it working using  and a YouTube tutorial - I had to change the code in the web.config file which is the part I missed. Thanks again